# inserting and removing USB 3.x flash drive "fixes" USB 3.2 SSD speeds (was running at 2.0 speeds before)

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, usb, ssd, lsusb

I recently purchased a SanDisk 2TB Extreme PRO Portable SSD (model SDSSDE81-2t00). Upon plugging it into my Linux machine to perform a backup, I noticed it was running slowly. After some tests with `dd` showed fairly low speeds (less than 50 MBps), I ran `lsusb -t` and saw it was reporting 480M, which is "high speed" USB 2.0.

```
$ lsusb
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:8001 Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 005: ID 04f2:b449 Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd Integrated Camera
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 138a:0017 Validity Sensors, Inc. VFS 5011 fingerprint sensor
Bus 002 Device 011: ID 0781:55af SanDisk Corp. Extreme Pro 55AF      <--- here
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

```
$ lsusb -t
/:  Bus 03.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/4p, 5000M
/:  Bus 02.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/11p, 480M
    |__ Port 1: Dev 11, If 0, Class=Mass Storage, Driver=uas, 480M      <--- here
    |__ Port 6: Dev 3, If 0, Class=Vendor Specific Class, Driver=, 12M
    |__ Port 8: Dev 5, If 0, Class=Video, Driver=uvcvideo, 480M
    |__ Port 8: Dev 5, If 1, Class=Video, Driver=uvcvideo, 480M
/:  Bus 01.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=ehci-pci/3p, 480M
    |__ Port 1: Dev 2, If 0, Class=Hub, Driver=hub/8p, 480M
```

After some more troubleshooting, I plugged in a known-working USB 3.x flash drive, which correctly showed as 5000M speeds.

```
$ lsusb -t
/:  Bus 03.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/4p, 5000M
    |__ Port 1: Dev 18, If 0, Class=Mass Storage, Driver=usb-storage, 5000M     <--- here
/:  Bus 02.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/11p, 480M
    |__ Port 6: Dev 3, If 0, Class=Vendor Specific Class, Driver=, 12M
    |__ Port 8: Dev 5, If 0, Class=Video, Driver=uvcvideo, 480M
    |__ Port 8: Dev 5, If 1, Class=Video, Driver=uvcvideo, 480M
/:  Bus 01.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=ehci-pci/3p, 480M
    |__ Port 1: Dev 2, If 0, Class=Hub, Driver=hub/8p, 480M
```

Then, I plugged back in the new SSD, and it reported 5000M speeds! I confirmed this test on a different Linux machine and saw the same results. Kernels were:

- 4.19.107 (an Unraid server)
- 5.4.0-64-generic (Ubuntu)

Also notable is that the driver was `Driver=uas` when speeds were low, and changed to `Driver=usb-storage` after it was working. Perhaps a kernel module was not yet loaded, and the flash drive caused it to load?

TL;DR:

1. new SSD shows usb 2.0 speeds (in practice, and as reported by `lsusb`)
2. unplug SSD, plug in USB 3.0 flash drive, remove flash drive, reinsert SSD
3. SSD speeds are now correct (in practice and via `lsusb`)
4. reproducible on two machines

**Why might this be happening, and what further troubleshooting can I do?** If this is a Linux kernel bug, I'd like to collect enough information to properly report it.

Answer (score 0):

I have a partial answer, which is that my kernel module theory was correct. I compared the output of `lsmod` before and after doing the thumb drive plug/unplug trick, and it was very clear:

```
$ diff lsmod.txt lsmod.txt2
36c36
< usb_storage            77824  1 uas
---
> usb_storage            77824  4 uas
```

After replicating this state via:

```
$ sudo modprobe usb_storage
```

I am able to get full speed on the drive without any other tricks.

I still welcome other answers that may provide more details.